# Angular ui router autoscroll on specific states

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that makes the window scroll to top whenever a state change starts:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(){
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

However, on certain states, I have partial views which are triggering the `$stateChangeStart` and scrolls to top too. I don't want this to happen on those views/states.

This is the routes:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myApp')
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('everywhere', {
    url: '/everywhere',
    templateUrl: 'client/everywhere/everywhere.view.ng.html',
    controller: 'everywhereCtrl'
  })
  .state('everywhere.instructions', {
    url: '/instructions',
    templateUrl: 'client/everywhere/instructions/instructions.view.ng.html',
    controller: 'everywhereCtrl'
  })
  .state('everywhere.instructions', {
    url: '/others',
    templateUrl: 'client/everywhere/others/others.view.ng.html',
    controller: 'everywhereCtrl'
  });
});
```

and the view:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="view" name="view">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center margin-bottom margin-top">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
      <li class="everywhere" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="everywhere.instructions">Instructions</a></li>
      <li class="everywhere" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="everywhere.others">Others</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div ui-view root-state="everywhere"></div>
```

How am I able to disable the autoscroll to top on specific states?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-router` allows you [attach custom data](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects) to each state. So you could add some boolean flag `noscroll` to the states where you don't want to scroll.

```
.state('everywhere.instructions', {
  url: '/instructions',
  templateUrl: 'client/everywhere/instructions/instructions.view.ng.html',
  controller: 'everywhereCtrl',
  // don't scroll for this state
  data: {
    noscroll: true,
  }
})
```

And then in your `$stateChangeStart` event listener you can check if the `toState` is flagged as `noscroll`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  if (toState.data && toState.data.noscroll) {
    return;
  }

  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Note how I added the callback function parameters to the event listener. [See the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).

If you wanted, you could flip this logic and only scroll to the top when a state has `scrollToTop` defined. Whatever makes sense for your use case.